# Using method on class or function in closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

Say I want to create a Simple React component with some methods (no state or life-cycle methods). I can do it one of two ways:

```
// Foo.js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  doSomething() {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    ...
    this.doSomething();
    ...
  }
}
export default Foo;
```

Or I can do it like this:

```
// Foo.js
const doSomething = () => {
  // do something...
}

const Foo = () => {
  ...
  doSomething();
  ...
}
export default Foo;
```

The second is preferable because it's a functional component (simpler, less overhead), but does the closure function come with any overhead / risk of memory leaks?

In general, if a component doesn't keep state or use life-cycle methods, which is the preferable way to implement the component?

Comment: It would be `this.doSomething()` in your first example, wouldn't it?

Comment: What makes you think the closure would have any overhead or leak memory?

Comment: except life cycle methods and `state` a `class` component can invoke handlers from parents and pass parameters upwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, if you:

- Do not want to maintain `state`
- Don't need to use lifecycle methods ( like `componentDidMount` )

it's better to use stateless functional components, which are fast and more readable. And no, you needn't worry about memory leaks due to closure. For more benefits of stateless components, see https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use class-based components if you are not keeping track of application state or life-cycle methods simply because it is a lot of overhead, and you don't need to keep track of the `this` keyword, which is frankly, annoying.

A functional component is dumb. It has no idea of the application state at all. It can be used to display / present the component without having to worry about updating itself when an event is emitted.

In your case, if the `doSomething()` method does not involve any dynamic behavior, it is preferable to go with the second approach.